# Bootstrap typeahead, Handsontable: using complex object/hash

Tags: jquery-plugins, inline-editing, handsontable

I am using JQuery [HandsonTable](http://handsontable.com/). It uses twitter bootstrap [typeahead 2.0](https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/blob/master/lib/bootstrap-typeahead.js) which supports data-source as an array for `auto-complete`,

`["BMW", "Chrysler", "Nissan", "Suzuki"]`

My requirement is to pass it a hash instead of array.

`[{value:1, name:"BMW"}, {value:2, name:"Chrysler"}, {value:3, name:"Nissan"}, {value:4, name:"Suzuki"}]`.

There is a newer version available for [typeahead](https://gist.github.com/1866577) but I could'nt get it working with Handsontable.

Comment: I am working on updating to recent Typeahead code. Meanwhile, the only suggestion I can make is to transform the object to the array where you integrate Handsontable with your code. Can you do that?

Comment: I need auto-complete data array on run time via an ajax call. on what event should i call ajax to get data for an autocomplete? source is called multiple times(like on click, dblclick). so i cant use ajax inside autocomplete source.

Answer (score 0):

Handsontable (version 0.7.0-beta, `master` branch) is now using unmodified Bootstrap Typeahead 2.1.1.

Does it work for you now?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately the new HandsonTable 0.7.5 (with Bootstrap Typeahead 2.1.1.) still can't pass a complex object/hash.